# Why does using a wildcard to halve the number of arguments fail with "Argument list too long"?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, arguments

```
$ ls  <path>/ | wc -l
52137
```

A full directory listing works. But attempting to shorten the number of files, I get:

```
$ ls <path>/*horiz | wc -l
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
0
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has one argument, the directory name, which `ls` loops over internally:

```
ls <path>/
```

Note however that this is not one argument:

```
ls <path>/*horiz
```

Here, the shell itself expands `<path>/*horiz` into all the files that match, and then launches `ls` with that list of matches.

You might try something like this:

```
ls <path>/ | grep -c 'horiz$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because with `ls <path>/`, you are asking `ls` to list the files of `<path>`. But with `ls <path>/*horiz`, the shell is expanding the asterisk into the actual list of files, like

```
ls <path>/<prefix1>horiz <path>/<prefix2>horiz ... <path>/<prefixN>horiz
```

but that list is too long for a single shell line, so it gaves you the error.